# Use AddForce to knock back Player after contact with Enemy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on my very first Unity game. It's still in prototype and will be very simple anyways, consisting of a cube as the player and spheres as enemies.

I'm trying to write a code with AddForce to knock the player a pretty good distance in an arc in the direction opposite of the enemy when they come in contact, but I still have a primitive understanding of how to use AddForce and can't seem to get force applied in any direction at all. The player just moves through the enemy.

Here's the only thing I could manage to scrap together and it is obviously insufficient:

```
if (other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") 
        {
            playerDead = true;

            Rigidbody rigidbody = other.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
            rigidbody.AddForce (transform.forward * 100);
        }
```

I can post a screenshot if it helps.

Comment: It looks like the collision is not being detected. Did you set up colliders correctly?

Comment: Not sure. I haven't done anything to the colliders. Only the player has a rigidbody. I might be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `transform.forward`, use a more tailored direction depending on the position of both units

```
public float speed = 100;

if (other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") 
{
    playerDead = true;

    Vector3 direction = (transform.position - other.transform.position).normalized;

    other.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce (direction * speed);
}
```

Edit: You *must* make sure that the rigidbody is on the game object calling the `OnCollisionEnter` function, it cant just be on any of the objects involved in the collision.

Comment: Didn't seem to work. I still just pass through the enemy. 

I made the variable "knockBackSpeed" but otherwise copied your code exactly. Is there something I'm not changing that I should be?

Comment: Try flipping the direction, so you do `(other.transform.position - transform.position).normalized`

Comment: Tried it. Same result. I'm not sure if there's some way i can copy my code to these comments like in the original post because I feel like I must be doing something wrong but I'm copying it exactly and its compiling fine.

Comment: Are you saying that after flipping the direction it is still going in the same direction as before??

Comment: The player just rolls through the enemy, even with a rigidbody on the enemy.

Comment: Is everything tagged correctly? Does a `print()` or `Debug.log()` fire off from inside the `if` statement?

Comment: You need the rigidbody to be on the gameobject that *this* script is on. You need rigidbody to call the `OnCollisionEnter`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment so I must make an answer.

You have an isTrigger set up apparenty. Be sure to turn isTrigger OFF or your player will walk through the enemy collider.

```
[SerializeField]
private float speed = 100;
private bool playerDead;
OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{


   if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
   {

   playerDead = true;

   Vector3 direction = (transform.position - collision.transform.position).normalized;

   collision.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce (direction * speed,0,0);
   //AddForce is a vector3 apparently and requires (x,y,z)
   // Also note that I'm getting errors with the "collision.GetComponent<>"
  // You're going to want to remove "collision"
 // I think the smarter approach maybe to declare a public Rigidbody variable ( Up Top )
    [SerializeField]
    private Rigidbody playerRidg;
    playerRidg = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(direction * speed,0,0);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution using coroutine which toggles a bool "spikes":

Player collision:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision){
if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Spike" )
        {           
          
            StartCoroutine(Knockback());
            
        }
}
```

Coroutine:

```
IEnumerator Knockback()
    {
        spikes = true;
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.3f);
        spikes = false;
    }
```

Whenever the spikes bool is true player will be moved

```
void FixedUpdate()
    {
        
        if (spikes ==true)
        {
            Vector2 NewPosition = new Vector2(10.0f, 10.0f);
            moveCharacter(NewPosition);
        }
        

    }
```